# How to access shared host files on virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, permissions

I have set up an Ubuntu 15.04 as a Virtual Machine with Oracle VirtualBox. I am running a LAMP server stack on that machine.

As I want to develop on my host machine, I mounted a local folder on my host machine into the VM, which is `/media/myfolder`. And I have created a symlink from `/var/www/html` to that folder.

I get `403 Forbidden` errors when I try to modify the permissions of folders or files, but any `sudo chmod 644 index.php` doesn't do anything (no error message either).

File permissions are

- For `/var/www/html`

  ```
  lrwxrwxrwx root root myfolder -> /media/myfolder
  ```
- For files in `/var/www/html`, e.g. `index.php`

  ```
  -rwxrwx--- root vboxsf index.php
  ```

Any idea how I can manage to access this proxy-alike workaround?

Comment: What is the file system type in the host? ExtN, fat32, ...?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae It's NTFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Apache does not have permissions to read index.php.

```
-rwxrwx--- root vboxsf index.php
```

In that case only `root` and users that are in the `vboxsf` group can read this file. Apache runs as different user (`www-data` in Ubuntu as fair as I remember), and this user is not in `vboxsf` group.

You can:

1. add `www-data` user to `vboxsf` group
2. change mount options to allow also for others (it depends on file system).

Comment: I do not think this is the problem, because the OP says that file permissions cannot be modified at all, never mind Apache access.

Comment: So adding www-data to vboxsf group might solve the problem.

Comment: Number one looks promising. I'll take a look into that and leave my feedback here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

1. Host > Settings > Shared Folders > Double click the share. Are
   Read-only and auto mount checked?

Please check this first.

2. From within the Ubuntu guest, you need to add all potentail users of the share (YourName, root, www-data) to the vboxsf group.

   ```
   sudo adduser YourNaame vboxsf
   ```

and so on.

Comment: I had read-only checked but deactivated it later. Will try to add users to group `vboxsf`. Thanks!

Comment: That did it. As @Krzysztof Sawicki answered first, I'll reward him with accepted answer. But thanks anyway!